# Label Text not displayed due to less width of its container

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, tablelayoutpanel

I have a label in panel. The width of text in the label is more than its container panel. Because of that the text in the label is not coming completely.
I have tried `this.label1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;` and `this.label1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` but both aren't working. Is there any way to solve this problem?

The label is in a `TableLayoutPanel` which is in panel. And I want to show the text completely in the first row only. Making `AutoSize` true of panel is causing other data to move from their position. Which shouldn't happen.

[image]

Comment: Just set the [`AutoSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) property to true (winforms), or `Width` and `Height` to Auto (WPF)

Comment: My dumb question as WPF labels don't have a Dock property. Thanks for editing tags.

Comment: @Rhumborl - `AutoSize` won't help me. Please see the image for better understandings.

Comment: Check the TableLayoutPanel.RowStyles Property.Maybe it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When hosting controls in `TableLayoutPanel`, you can to set [`ColumnSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumnspan(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) for your controls.

> Column spanning is often useful for positioning a control that is
>   considerably wider than its peers.

Select the `LinkLabel` at designer and in properties set `ColumnSpan` to `3`. Also set `AutoSize` property of it to `true`:

[image]

For more information see:

- [How to: Span Rows and Columns in a TableLayoutPanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171687(v=vs.110).aspx)